# Core Data + Composition Architecture

Tags: ios, core-data, composition

I am building a native objective-c iOS application that loads and displays posts from a web service.

There are two types of sources to gather those posts. The one is from the user's dashboard, the other is by searching for a tag.

First i tried to build a parent source class with two different subclasses. But that lead to duplicated code or exposed private methods. So i thought of using composition.
Now i have a PostSource class that declares a PostFetcher protocol that is responsible for loading the posts, and i have two different PostFetcher implementations.

There will always be only one dashboard source and 0 or more tag sources.

I am happy with the architecture as it is, but now I want the sources to keep track of which posts have already been displayed. So I added a PostHistory to each source. This is working fine, but now I want to save this history to core data.

I am very new to core data and have no idea about how to design this in the best possible way.

Can i use the same architecture when the Source is a core data entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to you question is: yes.

Your model is not entirely clear from the your textual description but Core Data is certainly a suitable framework to model such relationships into an object graph. Your description on how the model evolved over time is a great case study of how data models can grow unexpectedly with mushrooming new categories and entities.

Take the port to Core Data as an welcome opportunity to re-think your data architecture.